# Using operators in lists

Tags: python

I want to check whether a string is in a list AND check whether it is not in a list as well:

```
supplies = ['pens','staplers','flame-throwers','binders']    

m = ['pens','a']
b = ['',not]

for x  in range(len(m)):
    for j in range(len(b)): 
        print(m[x] , b[j] , m[x] + b[j] in supplies)
```

However I get syntax error on:

```
b = ['',not]
```

If I change this to:

```
b = ['','not']
```

then it does not run the operation and says that a not in supplies is False which is incorrect.

How do I enter not into list b so that it will run as an operator?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure exactly what you are looking for, but is it `'string' not in supplies`?

Comment: Do you perhaps want to xnor `b[j]` and `m[x] in supplies`?

Comment: I don't believe you can store operators in lists.  What, exactly, are you trying to do?  Why can't you just say `if item in supplies` or `if item not in supplies`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't store an operator in a list. Similarly try `foo = [+, -, /, *]`. It doesn't work -- an operator must operate!

What you *COULD* do is to create a function that performs that operation, and store that instead.

```
b = [("in", lambda el, lst: el in lst),
     ("not in", lambda el, lst: el not in lst)]

for word in m:  # why are you indexing this?
    for desc, f in b:  # or this?
        if f(word, supplies):
            print(word, desc, "list 'supplies'")
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, you are trying to figure out for each value in `m` whether it's in `supplies` or not. Try this:

```
supplies = ['pens','staplers','flame-throwers','binders']    
m = ['pens','a']

# this will iterate each item in the list m, no need to iterate over m indices in this case
for item in m:  
    print(item, item in supplies)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this might do what you're trying to achieve:

```
supplies = ['pens','staplers','flame-throwers','binders']    

m = ['pens','a']
b = [True,False] #True if we want to see if the element is in the list,
                 #False if we want to see if it is not in the list

for x  in range(len(m)):
    for j in range(len(b)): 
        print(m[x] , b[j] , b[j] == (m[x] in supplies))
```

Or, if you have no control over the format of b, a slightly more convoluted solution:

```
supplies = ['pens','staplers','flame-throwers','binders']    

m = ['pens','a']
b = ['','not']

for x  in range(len(m)):
    for j in range(len(b)): 
        print(m[x] , b[j] , (b[j]== 'not') != (m[x] in supplies))
```

Answer (score -1):

For example, you may use eval() function:

```
print(m[x], b[j], eval("'%s' %s in supplies" % (m[x], b[j])))
```

Variable b should be like:

```
b = ['','not']
```

Comment: Just be warned that eval is dangerous, particularly if the user has any control over what ends up in `supplies`